# How do I prevent a menu item from responding to a mouse over (without making it insensitive)?

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, pygtk, menuitem, appindicator

I'm adding menu items to an appindicator. I don't want them to behave like ordinary menu items: I want them to have normal appearance, but not to respond to mouse hovers and mouse clicks.

How do I go about doing that? Trying to grab the events before gtk gets to them feels brittle - it feels like there should be a better way.

Comment: I tried to create an 'appindicator' tag, but I don't have enough rep. If anyone's feeling generous, that would make this post more discoverable.

Comment: low occurrence tags don't really make a question more discoverable. They are even [removed automatically after 6 months if they still have only a single use](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags). If you want to make your question discoverable for people searching for "appindicator", then putting the word in the question text is sufficient.

Comment: Why would you want menu items that don't behave like menu items? That's a really terrible idea from a UI design perspective.

Comment: @ptomato: It sure is. But that's the joy of appindicators. The only UI they're allowed to have is a menu, but they are used to show non-menu-y things (take a look at the Ubuntu sound indicator, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you don't connect the "activate" or "clicked" event to any handler, the menu items will not respond to any click.

Answer (score 0):

(sorry, not enough rep to add a comment to @chavaone answer)

As mentioned in the answer, create the menu item but just don't connect it to any handler code.

For example in my Ubuntu appindicator `indicator-lunar`, found [here](http://launchpad.net/~thebernmeister/+archive/ppa) I have mostly menu items which are display text and do nothing when clicked.